# Send Java errors from Filebeat to Logstash

Tags: java, logstash, slf4j, elastic-stack, filebeat

Please help me change configuration in `filebeat` and `Logstash` to send Java errors, info etc.
My currently working system can send system logs.

filebeat.yml :

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
       # - /var/log/auth.log #if uncomment, filebeat will send auth logs

         - server.log

      input_type: log

      document_type: syslog

  registry_file: /var/lib/filebeat/registry

output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["10.13.34.96:5044"]
    bulk_max_size: 1024

    tls:
      certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"]

shipper:

logging:
  files:
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB
```

Logstash 02-beats-input.conf:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
        ssl => true
        ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
        ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
    }
}
```

10-syslog-filter.conf:

```
filter {
    if [type] == "syslog" {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
            add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
            add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
        }
        syslog_pri { }
        date {
            match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        }
    }
}
```

30-elasticsearch-output.conf:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        sniffing => true
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
}
```

In this case filebeat did not send information because
document_type: syslog
What I have to change in my configurations.

Comment: The path you specify in the Filebeat prospector is just "server.log" and it needs to be the full path to that log such as `/var/log/nginx/error.log` in order for Filebeats to read the file.

Comment: Also you're using the forwarder certificate under `certificate_authorities` in Filebeats, when that should be `ssl.certificate` and the CA that you trust has a certificate defined in `ssl.certificate_authorities` and not "tls."

Comment: `sasha@3560:~$ ssh Sasha@***.**.179.221
[sasha@hom-3 ~]$ ls
server.log `               
This file in the root directory. I also tried /*.log